# Why is this php mkdir / uniqid not working?

Tags: php, random, file-upload, mkdir

I have this piece of code that should create a random directory and move uploads there:

```
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . mkdir( 'assets/post/email_uploads/{uniqid(attachment_)}', 0777 ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
```

The path `assets/post/email_uploads/` already exists so the random folder should go inside `email_uploads`. The issue I'm facing is what to place between the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATORs` and have everything work.

When I try `mkdir( 'assets/post/email_uploads/{uniqid(attachment_)}', 0777 )` OR

`mkdir( 'assets/post/email_uploads/'.uniqid(attachment_), 0777 )` - The folder is not created and the upload is placed at the root.

When I try

```
$attchmentPath = 'assets/post/email_uploads/';
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $attchmentPath.mkdir( uniqid(attachment_), 0777 ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
```

OR

```
$attchmentPath = 'assets/post/email_uploads/';
$randomDir = mkdir( uniqid(attachment_), 0777 );
$newPath = $attchmentPath.$randomDir;
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
```

The folder is created at the root instead of the desired path and the file is not uploaded at all.

Comment: `echo 'assets/post/email_uploads/{uniqid(attachment_)}';` - now what does that tell you …?

Comment: single quotes or double quotes?? The function call needs to be escaped  before calling and variables should be within double quotes if they are to be parsed - within single quotes what you see is what you get

Comment: @CBroe when I echo that it outputs it as it is - `assets/post/email_uploads/{uniqid(attachment_)}` but when I echo out `'assets/post/email_uploads/'.uniqid(attachment_)` it outputs the desired path but still won't work

Comment: @RamRaider I've just tried it with double quotes - no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply adding a parameter - `TRUE` in `mkdir` I had left out. So the functional code is - `mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE)` where `$path` is the path to the directory to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this? The content of `uniqid` should be quoted (unless it is a constant ) and the function call to `uniqid` needs to be escaped from the single quoted string

```
$dir=mkdir( __DIR__ . '/assets/post/email_uploads/'.uniqid('attachment_'), 0777 );
$name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$uploadPath = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;
```

You could try a recursive function to ensure that the directory path exists

```
function createpath( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
    if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
        createpath( dirname( $path ) );
        mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
        clearstatcache();
    }
    return $path;
}

$targetpath=__DIR__ . '/assets/post/email_uploads/'.uniqid( 'attachment_' );
$path=createpath( $targetpath );
echo $path;
```

Comment: I just tried this - the `uniqid` folder is not created and the file is uploaded way outside the root

Comment: if you echo `__DIR__ . '/assets/post/email_uploads/'.uniqid('attachment_')` what does that yield?

Comment: `F:\Projects\xxxxxx\yyyyyy\src/assets/post/email_uploads/attachment_5a5f195cdd9c1`

Comment: Have you got write permissions on that folder path?

Comment: the uploaded file is found at `F:` while the random folder isn't created

Comment: and do all the folders in the path exist?

Comment: yes, all the other paths exist - only creating the `atta‌​chment_` is the issue